# jQuery JSON parse: undefined object

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have used jQuery's `getJSON()` to get data from a server. The response looks good to me. This is how it looks

```
{"user" :[{"username":"nupac"},{"username":"nupac2"}]}
```

When I do an `alert(Objects.keys(jsonResponse));` I get `user` in my alert box which is fine but when I try to access the data with `jsonResponse['user']` I get an `undefined`.

Why am I getting an undefined? I think I should get the array of objects.

Edit:

Here is the code with the real url,

```
 function getLMSLinks(email){
        $.getJSON("url?student=" + email, function(d) {
            alert(Object.keys(d));
            alert(d['user']);

        }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
            //alert("fail " + textStatus + " error " + error);
             console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
        });
      }
```

Comment: please provide more context of your code. How/when do you call it?

Comment: I added the code, please have a look. plus feel free to check out the url and the response

Comment: This site doesn't support jsonp. So how do you get `alert(Object.keys(d));` displayed? Is it really the code you are using?

Comment: I am sorry I just changed the server side implementation because I dont have time to fix this issue

Comment: So fix server implementation and THEN your code will work

Comment: I just reversed it back, can you take a look?

Comment: still get: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Yeah, I got past that using `-a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-securityo.th`. Plan on fixing it later.

Comment: So ask relevant question later, once it has been fixed... Anyway, your code should work so...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this

```
 var jsonResponse = { "user": [{ "username": "nupac" }, { "username": "nupac2"}] }
     alert(jsonResponse.user[0].username);
```

If it is a string, first you need to make it as object using

```
 jsonResponse =jQuery.parseJSON(jsonResponse);
```

then you can use like

```
alert(jsonResponse.user[0].username);
```

**Edit**

```
 $.getJSON("http://prinyautils.appspot.com/getLMSUrl?student=" + email, function(d) {
        alert(Object.keys(d));
        alert(d.user[0].username);

    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        //alert("fail " + textStatus + " error " + error);
         console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
    });
```

Comment: I get a `cannot get object at index 0 for undefined`. Something along that context

Comment: The actual response has 'lms' instead of 'username' so I changed that and i still get undefined. Feel free to check the response from the url